# Ruby: Reference the currently executing block

Tags: ruby

Is there any way to reference the currently executing block in Ruby for one-off recursion? For example, to perform a "deep" merge on Hashes:

```
hash1.merge(hash2) do |k,o,v|
  (o.is_a?(Hash) && v.is_a?(Hash)) ? o.merge(v, &CURRENT_BLOCK) : v
end
```

I know that I could just define the block externally and reference it, I am just wondering whether it is possible to do it in-place.

Comment: Interesting question. What is `h2`?

Comment: @EricDuminil My mistake, `h2` was supposed to be `v`. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for some sort of [Y combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Fixed_point_combinators_in_lambda_calculus) in Ruby. I don't believe this is possible to do in Ruby with ordinary blocks, but you can do something similar [with lambdas](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/215746#941676):

```
lambda { |x| p x += 1; redo }[0]
```

Alternatively, you could implement a Y combinator generator using methods or lambdas, as shown on [this RosettaCode page](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Y_combinator#Ruby).